# jackson custom deserialize not being called

Tags: java, json, serialization, jersey, jackson

I am having a problem where my de-serializer doesnt work.

here is the desirializer class

> ```
> public class sometypeidres extends JsonDeserializer<MyTypeWS>{
> @Override
> public MyTypeWSdeserialize(JsonParser jp, DeserializationContext ctxt) throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {
>     // TODO Auto-generated method stub
>     return null;
> }
> }
> ```

and the class i want to desirialize

> ```
> @JsonDeserialize(using = sometypeidres.class)
> ```
>
> public class MyTypeWS{
>   }

but nothing is geeing called.

Is there something more i need to configure for this to work?

More info:
I want to use jersy to invoke the deserializer in the controller

> ```
> @POST
> @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
> @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
> public Response addNewDataSourceAttribute(MyTypeWS myTypeWS) {}
> ```

Comment: How do you deserilize the data? Are you passing your class type to a  ObjectMapper#readValue method?

Comment: Could you show your `JSON` data and code which deserializes it? I want to see how are you using `ObjectMapper`.

Comment: i am using jersy and letting the framework handle the parsing. i'll updae the question to include the controller